# Communicate over Internet Client/Server

Tags: c#, networking, server, client, ipv6

I know there are many threads about this theme, but i can not make it. I want to send a letter or a number over the Internet(not Local!). I have tried it with Ipv6 and Ip4 but both did not work. If you can pls in C# or Java :c Here are some code samples:

```
//Server

            Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            sock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IPv6, (SocketOptionName)27, 0);
            sock.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.IPv6Any, 5005));
            sock.Listen(4);
            Socket client = sock.Accept();
            Console.WriteLine("Works!");
            Console.ReadKey();



//Client

            string ip;
            ip = Console.ReadLine();
            IPAddress ipad = IPAddress.Parse(ip);

            Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6,
                SocketType.Stream,
                ProtocolType.Tcp);

            Console.WriteLine("try to "+ipad,
                ipad);
            sock.Connect(ipad, 5005);
            Console.WriteLine("yesssssss");
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Check my documentation this will exactly explain how to set up a asynchronous socket:  http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/9638/asynchronous-socket#t=201704161247338408331

Comment: And under the remarks tab it will explain how to set up the socket so it can receive connections from outside your own network.

Comment: @TimonPost Sorry but the Code doesnt work for me :c Can you explain me what I need to change to make it work! That would be very nice of you.